Is it possible to use aspect-ratio as part of the calc() in CSS? Or using the element's own width as part of the calc()?
I know that I can use aspect-ratio to make the height of an element equal to a specific fold/portion of its own width, for example aspect-ratio: 1 / 2 will make the height of the element twice as much as the width. But what if I need some thing like height: calc(the-element-width * 2 + 2rem + 40px);, is there a way to do it (without using javascript)?
I know the are some hacks like using percentage padding-top/padding-bottom, but it only works when there is no content inside the element. The width of the element is not a fixed pixel number, so the var() function also won't work.

Does this answer your question? How can I get the height of an element using css only

One option is to utilize container queries and to use container-relative units like cqw or cqh to get the width or height of the container in any property and calculations. 100cqw is equal to 100% of the container's width. (Unfortunately, a nested element is required.)
But be aware if you need to support legacy browsers like IE it wouldn't work.


#box {
  container-type: inline-size;
  width: 200px;
  
  .content {
    background-color: salmon;
    
    /* (200px / 2) + 20px = 120px */
    height: calc(50cqw + 20px);
    
    /* 200px / 10 = 20px */
    font-size: 10cqw;
  }
}
<div id="box">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>




you are setting an explicit width so what's the point of container and extra wrapper here? You can reuse the width value within the height declaration as well.
